Density argument in $C^0$ interior penalty method for HJB equation (in the linear case). Proving stability(?)
This is my first question here. Please let me know if I am doing anything wrong
I am following an article from Susanne C. Brenner and Ellya L. Kawecki (ADAPTIVE $C^0$ INTERIOR PENALTY METHODS FOR HAMILTON–JACOBI–BELLMAN EQUATIONS WITH CORDES COEFFICIENTS, https://arxiv.org/pdf/1911.05407) and am trying to prove all results in the linear case, that is $\Lambda$ has a single element and $\sup_{\alpha \in \Lambda} \{ A^\alpha:D^2 u - f^\alpha \} = A:D^2u-f=0$ or in other words $A:D^2u=f$. For regularity we have $f \in L^2$, $A \in L^\infty$ and $u \in H^2$.
I have proved all results up to this point but this density argument I just can't do. I want to show that $\|u-u_h\|_h \to 0$ when $h\to 0$. My idea so far:
Construct sequences for $A, f$ such that $\{A_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\subset W^{1, \infty},\{f_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \subset W^{1,2}$ such that exists $u_n \in H^3$ and $A_n \to A, f_n \to f$.
$\|u-u_h\|_h \leq \|u-u_n\|_h + \|u_n-u_{n,h}\|_h + \|u_{n,h}-u_h\|_h$.
I think I am able to to show that the second term goes to $0$ by using boundedness and "coercivity" to show a Cea's lemma, plugging in the interpolant, and using some trace theorems and this theorem from
Brenner_Scott_The_Mathematical_Theory_Of_Finite_Element Methods_2008 Theorem 4.4.20. I think this is fine. However I don't know how to bound the two others. Now I feel like I want to show some sort of stability in the mesh dependent norm. Something like $\|u-u_n\|_h \leq c(\|f-f_n\|_{L^2} + \|A-A_n\|_{L^\infty})$, but I am not sure.
Also in the article I think Susanne used the definition of $g_h$ in some smart way. However I just can't do it. Choice of $g_h$ from article.
Any help is appreciated, let me know if I need to give more details.

This one follows from a few steps. It is true for the finite element solution, as it satisfies estimate (3.4) in the paper:
$$\|u-u_h\|_h\le \inf_{v\in V_h:v_{\partial\Omega}=g_h}\|u-v\|_h.$$
We do the following addition and subtraction followed by triangle inequalities to get
$$\|u-v\|_h =\|(u-g)-(v-g_h)+(g-g_h)\|_h\le\|(u-g) -(v-g_h)\|_h+\|g-g_h\|_h.$$
This gives us
$$\|u-u_h\|_h\le \inf_{v\in V_h:v_{\partial\Omega}=g_h}\|(u -g) -(v-g_h)\|_h +\|g-g_h\|_h.$$
For the first term, because $u-g=0$ on $\partial\Omega$, by the density of $H^3\cap H^1_0$ in $H^2\cap H^1_0$, for any $\varepsilon_1>0$ there exists $\xi\in H^3\cap H^1_0$ such that $\|(u-g)-\xi\|_h=|(u-g)-\xi|_{H^2}\le \varepsilon_1$. Then as
$v-g_h=0$ on $\partial \Omega$, we have that
$$\inf_{v\in V_h:v_{\partial\Omega}=g_h}\|(u -g) -(v-g_h)\|_h\le \inf_{v\in V_h^0}\|(u -g) - v\|_h\le|(u-g)-\xi| +\inf_{v\in V_h^0}\|\xi - v\|_h \le\varepsilon_1+ Ch \to \varepsilon_1$$
as $h\to0$.
Now due to the particular choice of $g_h$, we get $\|g-g_h\|_h\to \varepsilon_2$ for any $\varepsilon_2>0$. This happens because $g_h$ is the projection of $g$ onto $V_h$, we have that $$\|g-g_h\|_h\le\|g - w\|_h + \|w - g_h\|_h\le C\|g-w\|_h,$$
for any $w\in V_h$, and so
$$\|g-g_h\|_h\le C\inf_{w\in V_h}\|g-w\|_h.$$
Choosing $w$ to be a suitable interpolation, and applying a similar density argument gives $\|g-w\|_h\to \varepsilon_2$ as $h\to0$. That settles the $g$ term.
Overall we have obtained $\|u-u_h\|_h\to \varepsilon_1 + \varepsilon_2$ as $h\to0$. Since this holds for any $\varepsilon_1, \varepsilon_2>0$, we must in fact have $\|u-u_h\|_h\to0$ as $h\to0$.
